# trouble with fmincon in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to use fmincon in MATLAB and not quite sure what the heck the problem is. My function is:

```
function f = myfun(x4)

f = (C * x4 - d) .^ 2;

end
```

and I call it like this:

```
lb = zeros(3, 1);
x0 = [10; 10; 10];
[x4, fvalx4, exitflagx4, outputx4, lambdax4] = fmincon(@myfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[]);
```

but when I run it I get

> ??? Error using ==> mtimes
>   Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

However, I checked and C is 112x3, and d is 112x1, and x4 is not initialized at all because that's what I'm trying to solve for.  If I create a "dummy" x4 I can run
    (C * x4 - d) .^ 2
without a problem.

Any thoughts? I realize this is the same as using lsqr or rather lsqlin with a lb of 0, which is also equivalent to lsqnonneg, but that's the point: I'm trying to verify results from those methods in different ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here.

First, you need to learn how to pass in those parameters that are not optimized. The function myfun cannot see C and d, as functions have their own workspaces, unless they are nested functions.

Next, since you are computing a linear least squares subject to constraints, you need to return a sum of squares. fmincon needs a scalar objective. It does not understand what to do  when you return a vector.

Personally, I would not even bother defining an explicit m-file. Define this using a function handle. So perhaps you might try this objective:

```
myfun = @(x4) norm(C*x4 - d);
lb = zeros(3, 1);
x0 = [10; 10; 10];
[x4, fvalx4, exitflagx4, outputx4, lambdax4] = fmincon(myfun,x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[]);
```

The function handle can see the value of C and d, so once the handle is created, those variables are carried along inside the function handle workspace.

Notice that I used norm to compute the sum of squares, in fact, here a sqrt of a sum of squares. But where the sum of squares is minimized, then so is the sqrt of that number. Its a bit cleaner looking with norm.

Another option is to use a version of myfun that explicitly passes in the value of C and d. Here I've given myfun arguments, then essentially created a function handle wrapper around myfun. You could have done that with an m-file version of myfun too.

```
myfun = @(x4,C,d) norm(C*x4 - d);
lb = zeros(3, 1);
x0 = [10; 10; 10];
[x4, fvalx4, exitflagx4, outputx4, lambdax4] = fmincon(@(x4) myfun(x4,C,d),x0,[],[],[],[],lb,[]);
```

Comment: Thank you!! It worked. I forgot to post at first that I did declare C, d, and x4 global, so passing should not have been the issue, but I like avoiding more m files when I can and your way is much more elegant - and works!

Comment: How in the heck are you gonna pick an answer that solves your problem and nobody is gonna upvote it!? Can't stand that. I'll do it, good answer mate.

Answer (score 0):

The function that you pass to `fmincon` [should return a scalar value](http://www.mathworks.se/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html#f844862). In your function it returns a 112-by-1 vector. Maybe you need to change

```
f = (C * x4 - d) .^ 2;
```

to

```
f = sum((C * x4 - d) .^ 2);
```